# SQUID on Ubuntu 20.04 Server - Swap Directory - Permission denies

Tags: 20.04, swap, squid

I am just setting up a new proxy server and struggle to get the swap directory pointing to another point rather than the original one.

The system is configured to run all latest updates from Ubuntu and squid. The NVME disc is mounted to /squid and I created a directory called squid-cache as per following:

```
root@rockpi-4b:~# df
==> Deleted all non entries:

/dev/nvme0n1p1 479669932 33628196 421606076   8% /squid
```

the directory has the right access rights for the user proxy (thats the service squid should run on):

```
root@rockpi-4b:/squid# ls -al
==> Deleted all non relevant entries:

drwxr-xr-x  2 proxy proxy        4096 Mar 12 19:36 squid-cache

-rw-------  1 root  root  34359738368 Mar 12 17:48 swapfile
```

I configured the right folder in squid.conf and also defined the cache_effective_user and group to match the same UID "proxy".

However, squid still seems to have no permission to write into this directory, and I struggle to find the reason. neither SELinux nor AppArmor are running.

[image]

I installed the RockPi from the Rockpi image:
https://wiki.radxa.com/Rockpi4/Ubuntu

And so far, havent seen anything, which could prevent squid to access this directory.

A bit frustrated here, maybe too blind to the the right solution. Any thoughts? Of course I went through all google findings so far, but again, either I am blind, or.....

Dirk